# shell script approach to restart different services on different machines

Tags: shell-script, remote

I am trying to write a script to restart different services on different machines. Before that, I wanted to check with you guys if anyone has any better suggestions.

Usually, we connect to different machines and start/restart different services/scripts. I would like to automate it because the count of machines sometimes is more than 30 to 40.

The plan here is to have a text file with "server| service" and write a script to loop around a data on a text file where the first column hold server names, pipe symbol, and service I want to restart.

Example:

```
10.0.54.5 | samba
10.0.68.7 | parameter.sh
```

Please suggest a better plan if the above idea is not good.

Comment: Have a look at ansible, saltstack or puppet. I'd start with ansible since ansible is easy to use and quite intuitive.

Comment: Agree with @val0x00ff. Ansible is built for this. Also, if you want to have a nice GUI frontend, check out Rundeck: http://rundeck.org/